# converting from a string of numbers to a string of values in php

Tags: php

I have a string of numbers "2,3,5". I also have an array

```
[0]  pens
[1]  paper 
[2]  pencils
[3]  lead
[4]  trashcans
[5]  cars
```

I'd like to change "2,3,5" to "pencils,lead,cars"

Is there some simple way to do this or only a brute force method?

Comment: Yes there is. There maybe a few ways. But basically if you are asking if there is a existing function like `MakeTheChangesIWant()` No there is not. You will have to write a bit of code

Comment: Look up [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) in the user manual.

Comment: Brute force only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* do this with a one-liner, but it is (IMHO) ugly and I don't know if I'd recommend this in production because I don't know if there's some weird edge cases it doesn't account for,

1. explode on comma
2. swap values for keys
3. compute intersection
4. re-join

```
implode(',', array_intersect_key($array, array_flip(explode(',', $string))));
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/HQ7GB